# Generate Random SELECT sql with three columns name always in there

Tags: java, database, multithreading, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a class named `ReadTableConnectionInfo` which contains details about the table such as `tableName` and it's `columns`. I have written a multithreaded code in which I am supposed to generate a random select sql by using the column values from `table.getColumns()`.

Suppose for table1 it has 8 columns such as-

```
ID
CREATION
DATE
ACCOUNT
ADVERTISE
SELLERS
GEOGRAPHIC
DEMOGRAPHIC
```

Below is my code from which I am trying generate random select sql using the columns. Here `table` is the `ReadTableConnectionInfo` object.

```
@Override
public void run() {

        while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= 30 minutes) {

        final String selectSql = generateRandomSQL(table);

        preparedStatement = entry.getValue().prepareCall(selectSql);
        preparedStatement.setString(id);

        rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    }
}   
    /**
     * A simple method that will construct the SQL
     * and return back
     * @param columns
     * @return sql
     */
    private String generateRandomSQL(ReadTableConnectionInfo table) {

        /* generate random columns from 
             * `table.getColumns`, not sure how to make that
             */
            final String sql = "SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,  from "+table.getTableName+" where id = ?";

        return sql;
    }
```

Below is my `ReadTableConncectionInfo class` which will hold tableName and `columns list`

```
public class ReadTableConnectionInfo {

    public String tableName;
    public ArrayList<String> columns;

    public ArrayList<String> getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(ArrayList<String> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    public void setTableName(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }
}
```

Now I need to generate random select SQL in `generateRandomSQL` method from the `table.getColumns()` list. In all my SELECT sql, I will always have `ID, CREATION and DATE` and apart from that, it should be random

Sample SQL Example-

```
`SELECT ID, CREATION, DATE, ACCOUNT from table1 where id = ?`
`SELECT ID, CREATION, DATE, ACCOUNT, ADVERTISE from table1 where id = ?`
`SELECT ID, CREATION, DATE, ACCOUNT, SELLERS from table1 where id = ?`
`SELECT ID, CREATION, DATE, GEOGRAPHIC, DEMOGRAPHIC, ADVERTISE from table1 where id = ?`
`Other possible permutations`
```

Can anyone help me in building random SELECT sql with ID, CREATION and DATE always in there? Any suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: Why not just select all the columns and randomize which one you pull from in the destination code? It would be better than building dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yeah that was the one option I thought of. But we are trying to replicate production scenario which means people wont come to look for all the columns. Some people will come to look for three columns, some will come to look for 2 columns and some will come to look for all the columns. So that is the reason I am trying to build dynamic SQL.

Comment: And I guess you are trying to say, I should select all the columns and then just randomize the order right? if yes, then I am not looking for that basically.

Comment: Random cols or user selected columns ?

Comment: @arpit, what do you mean by user selected columns?

Comment: "some will come to look for 2 columns and some will come to look for all the columns. " how you know that how many columns they want to see   and which one to see? any kind of input. or you just want to generate a random select sql(By random i mean in 1st execution you may get 2 cols, in next you may get 4 and so on)

Comment: See my question. I have provided the sample sql example as well. Basically I have a while loop in my code and each time it will go and generate random sql and those random sql will have `ID, CREATION, DATE` always and few other columns which will be random.

Comment: With this line `some will come to look for 2 columns and some will come to look for all the columns.` I was trying to make a point that I am trying to replicate production scenario. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private String generateRandomSQL(ReadTableConnectionInfo table) {
    Random r = new Random(table.getColumns.size());
    int rNumber = r.nextInt();

    List<String> suffledColumns = new ArrayList<String>(table.getColumns());
    Collections.shuffle(suffledColumns);

    String columnsList = "";

    for(int i = 0 ; i < rNumber ; i ++){
        columnsList += ("," + shuffledColumns.get(i));
    }

    final String sql = "SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" + columnsList +"  from " + table.getTableName() + " where id = ?";

        return sql;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arsen for the suggestion. In your first point you missed something? It looks messed up somehow. And if possible can you provide me an example by which I will be able to understand more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm What You think I have messed up? :) Maybe there is strange the parameters like {0}, {1}? You should define this string as a static field in your class

Comment: Why do you have DATE in brackets? And why only {0} and{1}. I guess, I am confused now. If you can provide any code example that will benefit me in someway. I can learn few more stuff

Comment: Well DATE is reserved word in SQL, to avoid sometime fails I have define it in brackets. Do not get confused from {0}, {1} parameters these are just parameters which You will provide during generation time. {0} is the random columns list string separated with commas, {1} is the table name. Read about MessageFormat.format(...)

Comment: Thanks Arsen for the help. One problem with the above code. As I don't think so, it's a good practice to create Random object every time. As I have my while loop which will be calling that `generateRandomSql` method. It will be good if Random object is created once.

Comment: You can define it as your class level field. I think I will not go depper in such a details. I just resolved your main problem

Comment: Yup. Makes sense. One more thing I am getting this exception `Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to List<String>` on this line `Collections.shuffle(new ArrayList<String>(table.getColumns()));`. Do you know why?

Comment: I have changed it, cause shuffle return type is void

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
   String colPart="SELECT ID, CREATION_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE"
   Random rNo=new Random();
   int noOfCols=columns.size();
   int colCount=rNo.nextInt(noOfCols-3);
   for(int i=0;i<colCount;i++){
   string colToAdd=columns.get(3+rNo.nextInt(noOfCols-3));
   if(!colPart.contains(colToAdd))    
       colPart+=","+colToAdd;
   }        
    final String sql =colPart+" from "+table.getTableName+" where id = ?";
```

Comment: @Farhan comment if you want different then this. Because i'm not sure is this what you want.

Comment: In my case, I have columns as ArrayList of String. So last sql line will give an error.

Comment: @FarhanJamal ok i made the correction. you can use `get()` method.

Comment: With your approach, I will always be stuck to only four columns right?

Comment: Yeah any number of columns. It's just that, ID, CREATION, DATE should always be there.